How can big tags be merged (i.e., when the moderators' tools fail)?
When a moderator tries to merge a tag which is too big, they might get an error. Is there some workaround for such situations? For example, can the SE staff do the merging in some other way—after a request from the moderators?
I will quote from this answer on Meta Stack Overflow: Gold tag badges don't apply to synonymized tags.

The query (presumably) timed out with an HTTP 500 and a generic "an unknown error occurred". Because it's a database-level rewrite, there's a lot of stuff that gets rewritten. In addition to the 100599 questions (0.4% of all questions!) needing to be rewritten, there's also all the revisions associated with those questions, as well as some other things I don't remember. There's a lot of data to rewrite with that many questions, so it isn't surprising that the merger failed.

I will add that I am not a moderator on any site, so I only have second-hand knowledge of this issue. But since the merging of a relatively big tag was discussed on one of the sites which I frequent, I was curious what the options are if merging runs into a problem like this.

I would normally say that a DBA can run queries that will timeout under normal operations but in this case I guess most of the logic is interwoven between C# logic and TSQL queries. Someone would have to isolate the logic first into TSQL, or run a version of the code without timelimits on production. That all sounds non-trivial.

I wonder if the DB write failed, or whether the UI simply timed out while the query was still chipping away in the background
